# Never received an invitation to a board

Tags: trello

My boss created a board and apparently invited me using my email address - he sent me a screen shot showing my email address on his board. But I never received an invitation and when I go to the direct link to his board I receive "board not found, this may be private." I was in the process of joining Trello while the invitation was being sent. I've tried the Trello notification test link. Any ideas for working around this probelm and getting invited to his board? Should I delete my account, create a new one, and have him invite me all over again?

Comment: Have you contacted Fog Creek (the developers of Trello) about this issue?
https://trello.com/help
support@trello.com

Answer (score 1):

create your Trello account and have your boss send an invite to your account name (the name that appears in parentheses when you click on your avatar or initials or when you click on the account button) You should then receive a red notification of the invite.

You could also have your boss delete the original email request and send it again. That will resend you a link to join the board.